# Directory/Folder listener in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, directory, listener

I want to develop an application in blackberry that is running in background and should listen for change in particular folder i.e. whether the file in particular folder/directory has been added or removed.

I can achive that using FileSystemJournalListener, but my problem is that it listen or invoke every time when the file is added or removed every time in "ANY DIRECTORY/FOLDER". But i don't want that behavior, i only need some way or any other listener that listen for any change of files in a particular directory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Still you can probably filter the events by the directory which they relate to. Or create your custom class that does that and blackbox that behaviour.

Comment: Ya sure pajton. I can filter the event on particular folder, but it increase load on my application. Suppose if i filter event on "Camera" folder then it is ok, working fine by checking condition, but the main problem is that it fires each and every time even user change files in other directory/folder. That is my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am agree with pajton's comment, we should use [FileSystemJournalListener](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6022/net/rim/device/api/io/file/FileSystemJournalListener.html) there and just skip useless events.

With proper filtering it shouldn't cause any performance issue - this kind of functionality is exactly what this class is for. Why don't extand FileSystemJournalListener into some DirectoryListener with filtering by directories implemented and to FileListener with filtering for files?

We can cache latest viewed events retrieved from [FileSystemJournal.getNextUSN()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2api/net/rim/device/api/io/file/FileSystemJournal.html) in each listener (and of course, clear cache on filter change), so it will look only for the new file system events.

And don't forget to use treads there to loop over events - so app will continue execution without troubles.

Comment: Thank you so much Max Gontar. I got it.

Comment: Hey, I am pajton, not pajtron :-)!